# How to remove elements from queue in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, stack, queue

I was trying to use the queue inside javascript. I was referring [this link](http://codetunnel.com/9-javascript-tips-you-may-not-know/)

I was able to add to queue, but while trying to remove from queue i was not successful completely.

```
var queue = [];
var input = $(".text").text();
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  queue.push("<span class='charToFade'>" + input.charAt(i) +"</span>");
}
$(".text").text("");
for (var j = 0; j < queue.length; j++) {
  $(".text").append(queue.shift());
}
```

Input:

```
<div class="text">Phone</div>
```

Output:

```
Pho
```

you can check the [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/obrt9ag7/)

Can any one help me here

Comment: What are you trying to do in your fiddle? I am able to get Pho, which is what you wrote the code for.

Comment: i am trying to replace each character by a dom element, but i was making mistake inside the loop for the queue length. Thanks for the support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you are running into is that for each iteration of the queue an item is removed.

This changes the expected evaluation of the condition for the for loop because the length of the queue is changing each time, about half way through the var `j` is equal to the length of the queue.

I suggest using a while loop instead of a for:

```
while(queue.length > 0){
 $(".text").append(queue.shift());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While you loop the `queue` in each iteration the length will get reduced by 1. So It won't iterate completely.

```
var queue = [];
var input = $(".text").text();
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  queue.push("<span class='charToFade'>" + input.charAt(i) + "</span>");
}
$(".text").text("");
var l = queue.length;
for (var j = 0; j <l ; j++) {
    var e = queue.shift();
  $(".text").append(e);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, use for-loop:

```
var queue = [];
var input = $(".text").text();
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  queue.push("<span class='charToFade'>" + input.charAt(i) +"</span>");
}
$(".text").text("");

// change here
for (var j = queue.length; j >= 0; j--) {
  $(".text").append(queue.shift());
}
```